# Javascript - event.clientX & style.left - Mathematical Operations

Tags: javascript, events, math, pixel

I am stuck with a lil' problem over here. Let me explain:

`document.getElementById(" ... ").style.left` (horizontal position of object) will return a value like this: `100px` or `1129px`.

`event.clientX` (horizontal position of mouse-pointer) will return a value like this: `100`or `1337`.

I want to make math happen between these two. For example: `var x = ( document.getElementById(" ... ").style.left ) + (event.clientX )`

How can I do this, when one returns a value with `px`and the other without? How can I get a regular number/px-number out of this? It does not seem to work to just add a `(event.clientX) + "px"` or `document.getElementById(" ... ").style.left - "px"`

Best regards! Comment if something is unclear I suppose!

Comment: [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) and [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) are for parsing strings to numbers.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing addition on strings will make Javascript try to concatenate them instead of doing actual math.  Doing subtraction on strings that contain characters other than numbers will cause Javascript to fail in attempting to convert them to numbers and will give you `NaN`.

You'll need to convert the string given to you by `document.getElementById(" ... ").style.left` to an integer using `parseInt`.  `parseInt` will conveniently ignore non-numeric characters like those in 'px'.

So, if `w = document.getElementById(" ... ").style.left` you could get the number in pixels by doing `parseInt(w)`.  You can do math with the value returned by `parseInt` because it will be an integer.